# Dynamic setting the timestamp fields in superset dashboards

Tags: apache-superset

I'm building few dashboards in Apache superset. All my available timestamp fields are in UTC timezone. (for example fields are, class_start_time & class_end_time).

I want that in the timezone the dashboard is opened all the timestamp fields will be automatically converted.

For example, I'm opening dashboard in Norway , so the UTC data should be converted to CET timezone of Norway.

I have tried to add some value here in Hours offset but its not working.

Can you please guide how we can achieve this.?

**Just for reference :**
In Kibana dashboards (ELK stack) have feature to automatically convert the timezone into which it is being opened. So I need same thing in Superset.

[image: superset]

Comment: Which database type are you using? There are known problems with postgresql and this setting.

Comment: @Cloudkollektiv I'm using MySQL and MS-SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would be able to set this with environment variables when you start the program or container. In Apache Superset, this is not possible. There is an ongoing discussion on [Github](https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/19176) about this issue. One GitHub user posts the problem and workaround, which is far from workable:

> Daylight savings causes issues where users have to update datasource
> timezone offset for each datasource twice per year.

So the only thing you can do is update the hours offset twice a year. To make matters even worse, if you use Postgresql, this may not even be possible due to a bug as described [here](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/7958).

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column that contains the required date/time corresponding to the time zone of interest. Use this in the charts.